# Sort list based on multiple conditions

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of integer lists, like that:

```
A -> 10 10 1 1 1
B -> 10  9 9 7 6
...
```

I would like to sort them based on how many 10s they have, then on how many 9s, 8s, 7s, and so on untile the 1s

So in the example above A should be better than B because even if it has less total points, it has two 10s instead of only 1.

Code should be generic because I don't know how many numbers will be available for each case (sometimes 10, sometimes 5, or even only 3).

I developed something like that:

```
lists.OrderByDescending(a => a.Where(b => b == 10).Count()).
ThenByDescending(a => a.Where(b => b == 9).Count()).
```

and so on, but this is not generic...

I hope the question is clear... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comparer

```
public class Comparer : IComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public int Compare(IEnumerable<int> a, IEnumerable<int> b)
    {
        var aOrdered = a.OrderByDescending(i => i).Concat(new[] { int.MinValue });
        var bOrdered = b.OrderByDescending(i => i).Concat(new[] { int.MinValue });
        return a.Zip(b, (i, j) => i.CompareTo(j)).FirstOrDefault(c => c != 0);
    }
}
```

lets you order you lists of lists like so

```
var result = lists.OrderByDescending(i => i, new Comparer());
```

without iterating through each list *ten times* counting individual elements.

Comment: Great method! Why do you concat int.MinValue?

Comment: @Alessandro That's a barrier in case your lists aren't all the same length - it'll make the shorter list sort as less than the longer list. It won't work if you have other `int.MinValue`s *in* your lists but it doesn't look like that'll be a problem.

Comment: Ah, ok! My lists will be always of the same length, so I can skip this check, right?

Comment: Yeah, you can drop the `Concat` calls in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create query which orders lists by count of 10s, then compose query by adding additional orderings for numbers from 9 to 1:

```
var query = lists.OrderByDescending(l => l.Count(x => x == 10));

for (int i = 9; i >= 1; i--)
    query = query.ThenByDescending(l => l.Count(x => x == i));
```

For these sample lists:

```
var lists = new[] { 
    new[] { 10, 9, 9, 8, 7 }, 
    new[] { 10, 9, 9, 7, 6 },
    new[] { 10, 10, 1, 1, 1 }
};
```

Result will be:

```
[10, 10, 1, 1, 1]
[10, 9, 9, 8, 7]
[10, 9, 9, 7, 6]
```

It's simple, but not very efficient. If you need better performance, then consider creating custom comparer. Here is sample with comparer which uses zipped ordered sequences to check if all items in sequences are same, or get first item which is different:

```
public class CustomComparer : Comparer<IList<int>>
{
    public override int Compare(IList<int> x, IList<int> y)
    {            
        var comparisons = x.Zip(y, (a,b) => a.CompareTo(b));

        foreach(var comparison in comparisons)
        {
            if (comparison != 0)
                return comparison;
        }

        return x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);
    }
}
```

NOTE: If items in lists are not ordered, then you should sort them before zipping:

```
var comparisons = 
    x.OrderByDescending(i => i)
     .Zip(y.OrderByDescending(i => i), (a,b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

It works very simple. Consider two lists:

```
[10, 9, 9, 8, 7, 5]
[10, 9, 9, 7, 6]
```

It will create pairs of items in corresponding positions:

```
{10,10}, {9,9}, {9,9}, {8,7}, {7,6}
```

Then items in each pair will be compared one by one, until first mismatch will be found:

```
0, 0, 0, 1 (four comparisons only)
```

That means first list has more 8s than second one. Usage:

```
var query = lists.OrderByDescending(i => i, new CustomComparer());
```

Result is same.

Comment: I didn't know I could concatenate this linq expressions... is this included in the base library?

Comment: @Alessandro of course - you always can assign `IOrderedEnumerable` to variable of same type

Comment: Is it possible to write this a single Linq expression (without looping)?

Comment: this is a single query from Sergey answer, `Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Aggregate(lists.OrderByDescending(l => l.Count(x => x == 10)), (agg, v) => agg.ThenByDescending(a => a.Count(x => x == 10 - v)))`

Comment: @Alessandro don't be afraid of `foreach` loops. They are very easy to understand and often are more readable then appropriate linq queries

Answer (score 1):

This compares the lists and returns conventional comparison result - 1, 0, or -1 is returned depending on whether one value is greater than, equal to, or less than the other.

```
    static int CompareLists(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        var grpA = a.GroupBy(p => p).ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Count());
        var grpB = b.GroupBy(p => p).ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Count());
        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int countA = grpA.ContainsKey(i) ? grpA[i] : 0;
            int countB = grpB.ContainsKey(i) ? grpB[i] : 0;
            int comparison = countA.CompareTo(countB);
            if (comparison != 0)
                return comparison;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

First we convert the lists into dictionary of `number->amount of occurences`. 
Then we iterate through numbers from 10 to 0 and compare the number of occurences. If the result is 0, then we go to another number.

If you have `List<List<int>>` to sort, just use `list.Sort(CompareLists)` as in:

```
        List<int> d = new List<int> { 10, 6, 6 };
        List<int> b = new List<int> { 10, 9, 9 };
        List<int> a = new List<int> { 10, 10, 1, 1, 1 };
        List<int> c = new List<int> { 10, 7, 7 };
        List<int> e = new List<int> { 9, 3, 7 };
        List<int> f = new List<int> { 9, 9, 7 };
        List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>() { a, b, c, d, e, f };
        list.Sort(CompareLists);
```

Comment: There is only on list of lists List<List<int>> and I need to sort it based on the condition explained in the question!

Comment: you wanted to check if one list<int> is `greater` than the other, right?

Comment: but wait a moment, I can convert it to sorting of List<List<int>>